# Angular FormGroup validator doesn't preserve setError on FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have a form group to manage time of day as follows:

```
      time: new FormGroup({
        date: new FormControl(new Date()),
        startTime: new FormControl(null),
        startTimeMeridian: new FormControl(MERIDIAN.PM),
        stopTime: new FormControl(null),
        stopTimeMeridian: new FormControl(MERIDIAN.PM)
      }, [MyCustomValidators.futureDateTime()]),
```

Inside my `futureDateTime()` validator on the group I do some logic to validate the formGroup and if it's invalid I do the following:

```
control.get('startTime').setErrors(MY_CUSTOM_ERROR) // MY_CUSTOM_ERROR is a valid error object
```

or the same except on `control.get('stopTime')`. This works the FIRST time and appropriately sets the error on the FormControls when they first enter the invalid state. The second time though, they have empty error objects.

I set debug points to narrow down what's happening and my FormGroup validator is appropriately setting the error on the control again, but it looks like something within Angular's code is clearing the error object.

How can I set error objects on a control from a FormGroup validator?

EDIT:

I'm not sure what was removing my error, but I was able to change my error object structure to an Array of errors, and then set them on the FormGroup instead.

Instead of the formControls startTime or stopTime having errors, I now set them on the FormGroup and my UI will check for any relevant feedback inside the FormGroup's errors.

Comment: Do you set the error through custom validator?

Comment: Stackblitz example demonstrating the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z1kvgf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution from a different question on github:
[github solution to how to setErrors in FormGroups](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38191)

but fromgroup.valid didn't take this error into account in my code so I manually checked for it with a boolean parameter, in this example:

pseudo-code:

```
const timeError: boolean = "startTime before new Date()"
const formStartTimeControl = this.time.controls.startTime;
if (timeError) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        formStartTimeControl.markAsDirty();
        formStartTimeControl.markAsTouched();
        formStartTimeControl.setErrors(MY_CUSTOM_ERROR);
    }, 1);
} else {
    setTimeout(() => {
        formStartTimeControl.markAsDirty();
        formStartTimeControl.markAsTouched();
        formStartTimeControl.setErrors(null);
    }, 1);
}
// [...] other code
if(formGroup.valid && !timeError){
    // continue with submitting code
}
```

but that and that you have to set a timeout for the code to work makes it look like a dodgy solution to me, would be interesting to see if there is a better one out there.

Comment: In general use setErrors is a "bad idea", why not use a custom validator?

Comment: To be fair it would be an option, and if I have more time on the task I am working on right now, I'll probably come back to it, but it just seemed like setting the error was the quickest and easiest way for my use case. As I can vaguely remember it was an utter mess writing a validator that validates two different formControl values